# Sharing session between two different web browser

Tags: php, session, browser

I want to make a **PHP web application** in which on a single PC there can only be one authentication session at a time i.e. **User A** login using *Firefox*, but **User B** cannot login using *IE* on the same PC

Of what i googled session sharing between browsers can not be done if asked from server side

Comment: Hi Mesohisilis, welcome to SO.

Comment: or from the client side as one browser can't play in the others cookies

Comment: @Orangepill so it can't be done because its impossible for a browser to check session of other browser rite?

Comment: that is the unfortunate reality

Comment: correct, perhaps if you told us whats the problem if that did happen we could suggest an alternaive

Comment: Exactly right, Meso - browser instances can't communicate.

Comment: Explain why exactly you need that

Comment: Its an application working with financial transaction. My customer doubts in the ability of the end-user. To make it more secure for them they don't want more than one users at a time to login to the system  on a PC. This helps them clear of the supports topic of buy and selling on different accounts because the end-user used same pc with his grandma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically, you could do this using [session_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) and a database entry, although security will be tricky since a malicious user could try generating random session IDs to mimic a logged-on user's session.

Session information is stored in a cookie in the client's browser, with a specified ID.  By storing that ID and a JSON string of the data, whenever it's updated, various users could conceivably share the same data.  They'd all have to poll the server once in a while to see if the data has been changed.

But at that point, you don't need to use `$_SESSION` anymore, so it's pretty much defeated the purpose of your question.  You can get the same behavior with regular variables, which would already be a security improvement.

---

Short answer: No, that's not the point of sessions.

Comment: this will ensure that a given user can only have one session but it doesn't limit the sessions to one per computer.

Comment: @Steve Of what i understand u mean on the same browser rite? Actually forcing a single user authen in one browser can be done using DB session but what i really want is checking with two different browser.

Comment: @Orangepill - Using `session_id()` would limit it to one per browser, but you could do that anyway with `isset()` and regular variables...also OP wants to use "the same PC".

Comment: @Mesophisilis - yeah, you use the `session_id()` from the "original" session as a reference for the shared data.  But it's just an MD5 hash (if I remember correctly) so you could use regular variables anyway, just cached in a database.  Sessions are really only for single-browser use.

Comment: @Steve Thanks Steve, thats what i think and still believe it is, but this is a requirement asked so of what little knowledge i have i dont want to reject the possibles :)

Comment: Glad to help.  If an answer helps you out, people appreciate upvotes, and if it has answered your original question, go ahead and mark it "Accepted".  Good luck! My main advice: forget about sessions in this case, you'll just need to work with fingerprints and databases.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the login script such that as to it checks on login whether the user is already looged in or not. If logged in then it will reject any more further logins.

As said above PHP can store session ids in databases. Check the database for existance and then allow or disallow based on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this task (assuming your working with general users, who doesn't try to spoof User-Agents and other tricks) by using a signature algorithm which identifies a device. Your algorithm can have as many variables as you see fit.

For example REMOTE_ADDR, USER_AGENT. Other special variables can be obtain by executing a flash based code on the client side.  As each request comes in you can compare it with existing keys that are authenticated and if you get a new session where all variables match except a Browser String you can safely assume its the same user using a different browser.

You must collect extra variables using a flash component for this to work. the variables available via $_SERVER is not sufficient. Because there could be users behind proxies and you do not want to identify them as false positive.

Comment: Looks interesting to me, can you explain a bit more on how can i identify a device and what's the signature algorithm

Comment: Note that you've still got to cache the data somewhere.  This answer is discussing about how to identify that data.

Comment: Usually signature algorith generate a unique key by using the variables i discussed as inputs. It can simply be a `md5("$IP.$AGENT.$FLASHVER.$MAC)` in your case you can remove the $AGENT and generate it without the agent, so if when you try to create a new session you can check against a table of already logged in users keys and the one your trying to create if there is a match you can deny the access.

Comment: You can use flex to obtain the mac address. `http://littleprograming.blogspot.com/2011/09/flex-get-mac-address.html`

Comment: Of what i understand, we are not allowed to cache something at a specific place in the clients side, it looks dangerous to me. So asking them to do so seems ridiculous rite?

Comment: @DevZer0 Its possible to get the client MAC?? That's news for me. I've been googling about it but found non

Comment: @Mesophisilis: it's not reliable. This solution still doesn't guarantee anything. **WHY** do you need that?

Comment: @Mesophisilis i think its not realize as zerkms said. Its messy

Comment: Its an app doing financial transaction and my customer ask as one of the requirement/ I promised to give him an answer about the possibilities