# share a session across different pcs

Tags: php, session, localhost

I have a php page located at localhost/spiegel.php which displays a session. I now need another pc to browse to the same localhost/spiegel.php. The 2nd pc browses to 192.168.2.5/spiegel.php which is the first pc's ip adress. How can I show the Session from the first pc on the 2nd pc?

Comment: You cannot. Sessions are related to the domain, as are cookies.

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17562151/sharing-session-between-two-different-web-browser)

Comment: Answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17562151/sharing-session-between-two-different-web-browser